# JDK7: new features related to type variables?

Tags: java, generics, java-7

I remember to have read about a new feature of JDK7 *(now also supported by the Netbeans editor, yet only in current trunk builds)*.

This tiny feature wouldn't produce a warning anymore when `instanceof SomeClass<?>` is written *without* the type variable.

- How is this feature it called?
- Do someone know any reference, where it is described?
- Most important: **are there other changes in JDK7 related to type variables?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are speaking of the [Simplified Varargs Method Invocation proposal](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000217.html) from Bob Lee.  It was a coin proposal and is now included in [JSR 334](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=334) for Java 7 ([JSR 336](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=336)).

The only other change I know of is the Improved Type Inference for [Generic Instance Creation (diamond)](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-February/000009.html) change.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `<>` is called the "Improved Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation" or "diamond" pattern, and it is part of [Project Coin](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/editor/archive/2009/09/01/project-coin-final-update-list-jdk-7).

Although your issue (`instanceof SomeClass<>`) sounds slightly different.

Comment: That was approximately my reaction as well -- I didn't recall it being part of project coin, but that's the only source of actual language changes in JDK 7.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is related to **project coin** and its improved type inference when dealing with generics, take a look [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-February/000009.html). It doesn't seem the exact feature thou, just something related.